# Ignore missing files in copy bundle resource Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, git

**short**

I got an error:

> No such file or directory

But this is intentional. Is there a way to ignore this error? Or can I remove files from my copy bundle resources programmatically?

**Background**

I have an app for different providers. Every provider has different configs and get some different json-files. For example Provider1 has file1.json, file2.json, Provider2 has file1.json,file3.json, Provider3 has only file2.json and so on.

For every app upload the json-files can change (it's a settings thing). Now in my basic project I have references to every possible json-files. This files are filled with test data.

The work around is like this and full automatic:
Get individual json files for provider -> merge founded json files in my basic project and override existing jsons with test data -> start app upload with fastlane

Usually I uncomment all test data before I upload a new version. So every possible reference is okay in XCode.

Now I forgot to uncomment things and a provider receive wrong files with my test data.

To solve that problem I set a git ignore. So in my project are only the jsons files that the provider needs. But the references from my project file are still existing. So I understand why the error appears.

How can I solve that problem smart?

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem... it's dirty but it works.

In the merging process I clean my data by shell before the provider data override some of them:

```
cd goToPathWhereFilesAre
echo "" > file1.json
echo "" > file2.json
```

So my references are always correct and the content is empty, either the provider data are override them.

**EDIT and thanks @Anton Tropashko for the cleaner way**

```
cd goToPathWhereFilesAre
touch file1.json
touch file2.json
```

Comment: touch file1.json file2.json

Answer (score 0):

You should create a target for each provider. And set each file (config/json) with the proper targets...
Don't you ever work manually on differentiating versions!!! Good luck

Comment: I read a little bit about this idea, but I can't inspire by that. You configure the provider about an web interface. The data will save in a repository. I merge the basic version with the providers data. I don't want to put everything manually in my xcode Project. 
But good to know that this is possible.

Comment: i don't understand your english. don't you use Xcode to manage your dependencies?

Comment: I'm sorry for my english. It's not the best. Sure I use XCode. But I have an basic project. You can brand this basic project with provider data. This provider data implicit a lot of stuff (images, jsons, colors etc.). This data will be save in a repository. 
My basic project is in another repository. When I upload an app I merge the the stuff together an voilá there is an individual app.

Comment: And if you copy files by extension and not by filename, does it help?